# Unity3d app commit to mac os x app store reject: Apps that are not sandboxed appropriately may be rejected

Tags: unity-game-engine, app-store, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

Apple rejects Unity3d app commit:`2.31: Apps that are not sandboxed appropriately may be rejected.`

If I change to use "com.apple.developer.game-center", I can't upload the binary, error: `invalid code signing entitlements :libMonoPosixHelper.dylib.`:
 [image]

If I don't use "game-center" to sign, I can upload successfully, and I also removed the Identifiers' "game center" but they still reject me.

There're many people have the same problem now:

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/urgent-mac-app-review-team-rejected-because-gamekit-framework-linked.261354

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/mac-store-game-centre-entitlement-problem.265241/